# Best practice for saving images with unique filename

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best method to save uploaded images on my php server?
Say i have a database of works with an an image.
Should I add a random string to prevent overwriting other images? 
Should I create a folder with the unique Id of the work?
what's the best way?

Comment: i don't unserstand the downvote of my question: everything is an opinion base don experiences... and sharing experiences help to learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely up to you. A timestamp is always useful as unless you're uploading more than one image per second, they're guaranteed to be unique.

Chuck in any unique IDs, user IDs, attribute IDs etc.

e.g. < user_id >_< attribute_id >_20150219235959.jpg

Comment: oh yes, that's a good one!

Comment: `microtime(true)` if you need to save lots of images every second

Answer (score 1):

I prefer file name + date time

```
$removeExtension = explode('.',basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir .$removeExtension[0].date("m-d-y").date("h-i-sa").".$removeExtension[1]"); //renamin the file to the current time as e.g. cover_02-03-15-01-13-18pm.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be adding the upload time on the file name:

```
$time = date('his');

$filename = $originalfilename."_".$time.".jpg";
```

Comment: Two images uploaded on different days at the same time would get the same filename.

Comment: @delatbabel - but why would a user do that? User has to EXACTLY press the button in the exact hour, minute and second before that happens. So it works for me. But yeah, I upvoted Daniel's answer because unique ID is more secure to do.

Comment: If you just set filename to Filename_(time).jpg then ANY user on the system could get a duplicate file name against any other user on the system. A user probably wouldn't do it deliberately but it might happen by accident over time with a lot of users.

Comment: @delatbabel - Yeah, but the chance is still low considering that in order for that to happen is to have the SAME `file name` and upload it the SAME `hour`, `minute` and `second`.

Comment: No, any file name will do, you're not including the filename of the original request file in the filename that you generate. Any two requests at the same hour minute and second, on any day, will trigger a conflict. There are 86400 possible HMS combinations, if 30,000 files are uploaded then I would pretty much guarantee a conflict.

Comment: @delatbabel - So what you're saying is, if two users uploaded two different files, with different file name to one another, but uploaded it the same time, will trigger a conflict?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, that's what I'm saying. Take a close look at your code.

Comment: @delatbabel - the point of my answer is to take the original uploaded file name and just add a time string at the end. Of course before the extension (.jpg, .png, etc.)

Comment: "take the original uploaded file name" -- that's not what your code does, it takes the literal string "Filename_" and adds a time string to it.

Comment: @delatbabel - dude! **IDEA**!

Comment: People asking on this site should not take answers literally, where they will just be feed with answers and just copy+paste the code to their work. They should still get the **idea** and take it on their side/end.